# Typescript compiled file cant find a module with at sign "@"

Tags: javascript, typescript

for context: I want to build and run manually a project that I manage with NX.

I build the project with `nx build` and afterwards a `dist` directory is created with a main.js file. When I run it with `node dist/main.js` I get:`Error: Cannot find module '@my-project/server'`. Although if I run normally via `nx start` all starts normally and works. Anyone knows what can be done to solve?

Edit:

Project structure:

```html
|____jest.config.ts
|____dist
| |____my-project
| | |____main.js
| | |____src
| | |____config
| | |____pnpm-lock.yaml
| | |____package.json
| | |____server
| |____config
| | |____src
| | |____README.md
| | |____package.json
| |____package.json
| |____server
| | |____src
| | |____README.md
| | |____package.json
|____.git
|____src
| |____main.ts
| |____index.d.ts
| |____global.d.ts
| |____assets
| | |____.gitkeep
|____tmp
| |____my-project
| | |____main-with-require-overrides.js
| |____org
| | |____main-with-require-overrides.js
| |____libs
| | |____server
| |____server
|____Dockerfile
|____project.json
|____config
| |____jest.config.ts
| |____src
| | |____index.ts
| | |____lib
| |____project.json
| |____tsconfig.lib.json
| |____README.md
| |____tsconfig.spec.json
| |____tsconfig.json
| |____package.json
| |____.eslintrc.json
|____jest.config.app.ts
|____README.md
|____.eslintrc.base.json
|____tsconfig.spec.json
|____jest.preset.js
|____tsconfig.json
|____package-lock.json
|____node_modules
|____pnpm-lock.yaml
|____package.json
|____tsconfig.app.json
|____.gitignore
|____nx.json
|____server
| |____jest.config.ts
| |____src
| | |____index.ts
| | |____lib
| |____project.json
| |____tsconfig.lib.json
| |____README.md
| |____tsconfig.spec.json
| |____tsconfig.json
| |____package.json
| |____.eslintrc.json
```

tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@my-project/server": ["server/src"],
      "@my-project/config": ["config/src"],
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules_old", "tmp"]
}
```

Comment: What does your project structure and tsconfig look like?

Comment: I edited and added both, thanks for helping.

Comment: Could you make sure `@my-project/my-module` is visible somewhere in the project structure please? Also please consider posting it as text and [not an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). To do this you can use a command like this `find . -maxdepth 3 -not \( -path "./node_modules/*" -o -path "./.git/*" \) -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'` on a UNIX-like OS to print the tree which you can copy and paste into your question. Alternatively, here's an [online tool](https://tree.nathanfriend.io/) to create a tree manually.

Comment: I did, thanks again